# Outer merging two data frames in place in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, outer-join

How can I outer merge two data frames in place in pandas?

For example, assume we have these two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[1234567000,1234567005,1234567009],
    'X1':[96.32,96.01,96.05]
},columns=['time','X1'])  # to keep columns order

s2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[1234567001,1234567005],
    'X2':[23.88,23.96]
},columns=['time','X2'])  # to keep columns order
```

They could be merged with [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (`s3 = pd.merge(s1,s2,how='outer')`) or with  [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) (`s3=s1.merge(s2,how='outer')`), but it isn't in place. Instead, I'd like the merged data frame to replace s1 in memory.

Comment: Are you even sure avoiding copies is possible? There's a `copy` kwarg that ["*If False, do not copy data unnecessarily*"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but playing around with it and `np.share_memory` suggests that in your example the result is always copied. Which is not that surprising, considering that the resulting dataframe is quite different from the originals. But I'm not very experienced with pandas so my impressions might be way off.

Comment: What do you mean "it isn't in place"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndrewL I'd like the merged data frame to replace s1 in memory.

Comment: well since there isn't any `inplace` parameter i think the most you can do here is `s1 = pd.merge(s1,s2,how='outer')`, other than that, there's not much left to do i think.. sorry

Comment: @RayhaneMama Thanks. You're welcome to convert the comment into an answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak FYI [What are the exact downsides of copy=False in DataFrame.merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32330490/395857)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm probably not qualified to answer, though:) My hunch is that copying can only be avoided in very special cases (considering that `.merge` is a very general workhorse that provides all sorts of operations), when the result verbatim contains columns of the original dataframe(s).

Comment: Franck FYI [I tried to investigate anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992292/5067311). I convinced myself that the `copy` kwarg is mostly for show unless one's doing something trivial/weird. In your case I suspect there are bunch of actual concatenations going on, so no skipping copies for you :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since there is not `inplace` parameter in [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) i think the most you can do is:

```
s1 = pd.merge(s1,s2,how='outer')
```

other than that, i don't think there's much left to do.
Hope that was helpful somehow.

Comment: It is really a pity that there is no in-place merge or join (even with restriction that indices must match).

Comment: this solution does not perform an "inplace" substitution. It replaces the initial s1 reference by a new one. So it does not behave the same especially if you pass the s1 dataframe to a function and perform the merge within the function...

Comment: @jeromerg exactly, that's because, as pointed out by Rayhane himself and the whole of the pandas library, there ISN'T a way to perform an inplace substitution through pandas. That's clear enough from the short answer text itself...

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer is correct, there is no built-in way to this. Here are a couple ways I found to fake it in certain scenarios. They're likely quite slow, but they do suffice to minimize memory footprint. Use at your own risk.

```
s1["X2"] = float("NaN")

for i, row in s2.iterrows():
    if row.time in s1.time.values:
        s1.loc[s1.time == row.time, "X2"] = row.X2
    else:
        s1.loc[len(s1), :] = row
```

or

```
for _, row in s2.loc[s2.time.isin(s1.time)].iterrows():
    s1.loc[s1.time == row.time, "X2"] = row.X2

for _, row in s2.loc[~s2.time.isin(s1.time)].iterrows():
    s1.loc[len(s1), :] = row
```